# spring 3.0 with openjdk 11 issue with hiberante annotation class

Tags: spring

I am getting following error when I tried to build the spring 3.0 application in open jdk11. Iam using org.springframework.orm-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar.

`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to required type 'java.lang.Class[]' for property 'annotatedClasses'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class [com.nrift.model.EmployeeBean]`

in spring-servlet file its written

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"       class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">none</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
       <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.nrift.model.EmployeeBean</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Its working perfectly with jdk 1.7_80 version.Any help is appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: `com.nrift.model.EmployeeBean` - have you checked that it's contained in your deployment and that the class path and base-package are set correctly?

Comment: YES bcz its working perfectly with jdk 1.7